# How can I switch nested navigation graph in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For example, I have two graphs: LoginGraph and HomeGraph.
I want all the screens from the LoginGraph column to be shown to the user on the first visit to the application. Then, with successful authorization, I would save the boolean flag somewhere, for example, in shared preferences.

After the restart, I would read, if the flag is true, then show all the screens from the HomeGraph.

It is possible to explain a simple concept without full code (A plus would be with code fragments)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RootNavigationHost(navController: NavHostController) {

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "Auth", route = "Root") {

        addAuthGraph(navController)
        addMainGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addAuthGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(
        route = "Auth",
        startDestination = "Auth1"
    ) {
        composable("Auth1") {
            AuthScreen() {
                navController.navigate("Auth2")
            }
        }
        composable("Auth2") {
            PersonalDataScreen() {
                navController.navigate("Main")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addMainGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(
        route = "Main",
        startDestination = "Home"
    ) {
        composable("Home") {
            HomeScreen() {
                navController.navigate("Other")
            }
        }
        composable("Other") {
            OtherScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add what you have tried so far and create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I corrected the question. I want that when the user is logged in, app start on Main graph.

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09qjn706ITA&t=273s

Comment: @Rafiul I didn't understand the logic, it turns out we always navigate to the authorization fragment, do a check and then go to the main fragment, otherwise we log in. Just a couple of milliseconds, the authorization fragment will always be displayed. If I misunderstood, correct)
And there's an example for a regular Jeptack, but no Compose)

Comment: Hey! @Shurick7 Firstly you need make your start destination route variable and then you need to read your flag and validate your user after doing this you need to set your navigation route as start destination in your case `Auth` or `Main` and call your `RootNavigationHost("Main or Auth")`